# How can I calculate all the "unique" intervals and sum a column in a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

Considering the following Pandas Dataframe, where `Start` and `End` are timestamps and `N` is some numerical value:

| Id | Start | End | N |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 10 | 10 |
| 2 | 0 | 10 | 10 |
| 3 | 10 | 20 | 5 |
| 4 | 15 | 25 | 10 |

The desired output is the sum of the values of the column `N` for each intervals, including the overlaps.
In this example, the result would be:

| Start | End | Sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 10 | 20 |
| 10 | 15 | 5 |
| 15 | 20 | 15 |
| 20 | 25 | 10 |

In a step chart:

[image]

How can I extract all possible intervals and calculate the sum of all values in the 'n' column for all overlaps in a Pandas Dataframe?

I've tried to write an SQL query to identify overlaps:

```sql
SELECT
    B.start_timestamp as start_time,
    A.end_timestamp AS end_time
FROM process A
CROSS JOIN process B
ON 
  (B.start_timestamp > A.start_timestamp AND B.start_timestamp < A.end_timestamp);
```

However, this query only identifies the overlapping intervals, such as (15 -> 20), and does not solve the problem.

Comment: You should add the tag SQL and remove the pandas and python tag if you want a pure SQL answer.

Comment: Actually SQL was the best I could think of to solve this problem, but I'm open to any solutions.

Comment: Given the data is sorted by start time, This would be an O(n) problem, similar to the [meeting room problem](https://aaronice.gitbook.io/lintcode/sweep-line/meeting-rooms). An SQL solution is less viable than, say, a Python one. Because the solution involve basic loop, Pandas wouldn't provide much advantage. Either SQL or Pandas can be used to aggregate data by `(Start, End)`. **Note** one can do bucket count if time resolution is not super great.

Answer (score 1):

I got a solution, but it is far away to be optimized. I do several passes on the intervals, may be someone will have a smarter idea… I wonder if an interval tree could be worth to check if the intervals overlap (it depends on how big of data you have).

```
Input:
  start  end   N
0      0   10  10
1      0   10  10
2      5   15  10
3     10   20   5
4     15   25  10
5     35   45  10

Output:
   start  end   N
0      0    5  20
1      5   10  30
2     10   15  15
3     15   20  15
4     20   25  10
5     35   45  10

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 10, 10],
                   [0, 10,  10],
                   [5, 15,  10],
                   [10, 20, 5],
                   [15, 25, 10],
                   [35, 45, 10]], columns=["start", "end", "N"])

start = df["start"].values
end = df["end"].values
N = df["N"].values

intervals = list(zip(start, end))



def intersect(A, B):
    if not (A[0] >= B[1] or A[1] <= B[0]):
        return True

def cut_interval(A, B):
    splitted = []
    splitted.append((min(A[0], B[0]), max(A[0], B[0])))
    splitted.append((max(A[0], B[0]), min(A[1], B[1])))
    splitted.append((min(A[1], B[1]), max(A[1], B[1])))
    return splitted

def get_uniq_interval(intervals):

    interval = sorted(list(set(intervals)))

    N = len(interval)
    if N == 0:
        return AssertionError("empty intervals")

    cut_intervals = []
    for A in interval:
        for B in interval:
            if intersect(A,B) and not A == B:
                cut_intervals.extend(cut_interval(A, B))

    # if non overlapping interval we need to add it
    cut_intervals = list(set(cut_intervals))
    to_add = []


    for A in interval:
        inter = False
        for B in cut_intervals:
            if intersect(A, B):
                inter = True
        if not inter:
            to_add.append(A)
    to_add = list(set(to_add))

    cut_intervals.extend(to_add)
    return sorted(cut_intervals)

uniq_interval = get_uniq_interval(intervals)

N_new = [0] * len(uniq_interval)
for indice_b , B in enumerate(uniq_interval):
    for i, A in enumerate(intervals):
        if intersect(A, B):
            N_new[indice_b] += N[i]

# almost there!

df_new = pd.DataFrame(uniq_interval, columns=["start", "end"])
df_new["N"] = N_new

print(df)
print(df_new)
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I don't know SQL, so I'm not sure which parts of this you've already figured out, but here's how I solved it:

#### Unique intervals

The endpoints are just the sorted unique elements in either `Start` or `End`:

```
endpoints = sorted(set(df['Start']).union(df['End']))
```

```
[0, 10, 15, 20, 25]
```

To pair them up, slicing is enough:

```
intervals = pd.DataFrame({'Start': endpoints[:-1], 'End': endpoints[1:]})
```

#### Sum of original data

We can calculate the sum of `N` for each original interval just with `groupby`:

```
sums = df.groupby(['Start', 'End'])['N'].sum()
```

```
Start  End
0      10     20
10     20      5
15     25     10
Name: N, dtype: int64
```

(You could add `sort=False` to `groupby` if the input data is already sorted.)

#### Finding overlaps and summing

This is the most difficult part. The method I found is *O(n^2)* and not vectorized, simply comparing each unique interval with each original interval. (Although, you haven't mentioned if performance should be a concern.) To identify overlaps, I'm treating the intervals as closed, which requires a weird-looking comparison.

```
intervals['Sum'] = intervals.apply(
    lambda row: sum(
        n for (start, end), n in sums.items()
        if start <= row['Start'] < end or start < row['End'] <= end),
    axis=1)
intervals
```

```
   Start  End  Sum
0      0   10   20
1     10   15    5
2     15   20   15
3     20   25   10
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried it in a small sample of my data, and in fact it works. But, the real data actually have hundred of megabytes, so this approach would take a very long time. I'm trying to write some optmized algorithm, but maybe this problem is more difficult than I thought.

Comment: You may use an interval tree for the last part that could drastically reduce the complexity.

Comment: @G.Bittencourt I figured ;) It'd help if you mentioned that in the question.

Comment: @RomainL. What would you recommend? I found [intervaltree](https://pypi.org/project/intervaltree/) from a quick google, but it says the lower bound is included, which I don't think would work.